# How to get unique IP (and number of banned times) from fail2ban logs

Tags: shell, logging, uniq, fail2ban

I have a lot banned IP from `fail2ban` log. This have this format:

```
[...]
2021-02-28 00:03:33,818 fail2ban.filter         [687]: INFO    [sshd] Found 193.142.146.33 - 2021-02-28 00:03:33
2021-02-28 00:07:17,068 fail2ban.filter         [687]: INFO    [sshd] Found 193.142.146.33 - 2021-02-28 00:07:16
2021-02-28 00:08:49,568 fail2ban.filter         [687]: INFO    [sshd] Found 142.93.234.120 - 2021-02-28 00:08:49
[...]
```

I want to transform that to a list of unique IP with number of banned times (with the previous example):

```
2 193.142.146.33
1 142.93.234.210
```

Comment: `uniq` (`zcat /var/log/fail2ban.log.4.gz | grep ssh | uniq -c - | less`) does not work, because the time shot is different. So I need some preprocess before call `uniq`.

Comment: It seems that `zcat /var/log/fail2ban.log.4.gz | grep -Eo "[^^][0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}" | uniq -c | sort` solves my problem. Is any better solution?

Comment: NOTE:  `[^^]` is not matching not at the beginning of the line, it's saying a character that isn't the `^` character - which looking at the sample seems irrelevant.

Comment: Also note that your original was going to filter out other IP addresses that weren't from sshd ... the revised will match other things that include IP address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the lines of the log follow the same template as those three, with no extra spaces anywhere:

```sh
zcat /var/log/fail2ban.log.4.gz | awk '{ print $8 }' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1rn
```

Note that `uniq` expects its input to be sorted. The final `sort` in the pipeline will show the most frequently occurring addresses first.

---

Or using `perl`'s [`Regexp::Common`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common) module to get a robust regular expression to extract all IPv4 addresses from each line:

```sh
zcat /var/log/fail2ban.log.4.gz | perl -MRegexp::Common=net -nE 'say for m/\b$RE{net}{IPv4}\b/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1rn
```

Comment: What `awk '{ print $8 }'` really means?

Comment: Print the eight column of each line.